# Corda 4.5 Template Project

Tags: java, corda

I amtrying to build a corda demo application using corda os 4.5. Is there any template that uses corda 4.5. The template that I cloned, https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java, uses corda 4.4. What would I have to do in order to upgrade to corda 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to `constants.properties` file inside your cloned template, then change `cordaVersion` and `cordaCoreVersion` from 4.4 to 4.5.

If Gradle doesn't ask automatically to download the new versions; you can go (inside Intellij) to View-> Tool Windows -> Gradle then click on the refresh icon in the Gradle window so it refreshes your project with the new versions.

Comment: Hi, I have created a different question but seem to get no answer from community. When running in a server for a node I get this error:  Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable. Would you know what could solve this issue?